# Is there a package that provides the "additional functionality" required by l3kernel?

Tags: expl3, latex3

The `README.md` file for the `l3kernel` package says that the package "requires the e-TeX extensions and additional functionality to support string comparisons, expandable character generation with arbitrary category codes (for Unicode engines) and PDF support primitives (where direct PDF generation is used)."  As an alternative to using `pdfTeX` or `XeTeX` etc., is it possible to create a style file that adds the required "additional functionality"?  If so, does such a package exist?  If so, but no such package exists, is there a list of the required functionality somewhere that I could use to create such a package?  Or is putting the additional functionality in a package technically impossible? I have searched `expl3-code.tex` and the documentation files `expl3.pdf` and `interface3.pdf`, as well as the web, but I'm not sure I have searched for the right terms.

Comment: no the required functionality has to be provided by the Tex program you  cant provide it in macros which is why expl3 requires it rather than implementing it

Comment: I wonder what your use case is: pdfTeX, etc. are completely standard engines.

Comment: the engines in texlive and miktex provide everything needed

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you point me to a technical description somewhere of the required functionality?

Comment: the pdftex manual describes all the extra commands and the pdftex source is effectively the reference implementation

Comment: @JosephWright I use a niche editor, which is no longer under development, that shows the source in one window and the exact output in another window, and allows either of them to be edited.  When either the source or the output is edited, the other updates simultaneously.  For the documents I produce, having that functionality saves me a huge amount of time.  Other editors update the output with delay, sometimes only when the user presses a specific key, but none that I know update it instantly and automatically.

Comment: the editor is not related to the typesetting though, the question is which tex system you use any tex engine under current development has all the features needed. lots of systems have automatic updating of the preview notably the online overleaf system,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In all the systems I have tried, including Overleaf, the updating is somewhere between slow and extremely slow.  In BaKoMa it's instant --- there is absolutely no delay, regardless of the length of the document, and the output can be edited directly.  (Most of the time I compose in the output window.)  At the moment, the amount of time I save by using BaKoMa outweighs the loss of features in packages that use LaTeX3.  At some point, that inequality might reverse --- but perhaps not in my lifetime (I'm getting old!).

Comment: note that it's not "latex3` as a separate system: the expl3 macros are a core part of the latex2e format, the required features are required to run a current latex. Personally I don't use the preview at all much when writing, I'd write a page or two as source and then just run latex every now and then, but people vary. Which commands is bakoma tex missing?

Comment: Stackexchange says we're not supposed to have extended discussions in comments (no idea why that is), and we should "move this discussion to chat".  I don't know what that means, but I'm going to click the link ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132442/discussion-between-martin-j-osborne-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: hello, it moves the comments here..